# How to check if a variable/parameter is a function in racket

Tags: function, variables, parameters, racket

I hope someone can help me.

I need to find a way to check if a given parameter/variable is a function (function meaning something like * or + or expt, something I can use on two numbers later on like this:(* 5 6)) in racket.

Comment: Can show what all have you been trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`procedure?` does that:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.11.
> (procedure? +)
#t
> (define x 1)
> (procedure? x)
#f
> (define y (lambda () 1))
> (procedure? y)
#t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `procedure?` ([see the manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html)):

> (procedure? v) → boolean?
>
> v : any/c
>
> Returns #t if v is a procedure, #f otherwise.

```
> (procedure? +)
#t
```